# jsignature signature not displaying on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, samsung-mobile

Using jSignature (https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature) within a PhoneGap, JQuery Mobile application.

When trying to sign in the content div using the Samsung Galaxy S4 the drawn line is not displaying. The signature is there when I pull the data but is for some reason not displaying. Any ideas why this might be?  It has been working on other devices such as Samsung Galaxy S3, iPhone, and iPad.

```
<script>
    var signatureContentDiv = $("#signatureContentDiv");
    signatureContentDiv.html("");
    signatureContentDiv.jSignature();
</script>

<div id="signatureContentDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also just run into this.  For me, the error appears on the Galaxy Note 2.0 while running Chrome.  I tried changing to Firefox and it works properly.  The same behavior is noted when trying the demo directly on jSignatures site.  I would suggest checking against their site and seeing if your device works properly to eliminate your code being the issue.

Hopefully this will get fixed.

Additional Info: I have just determined that it seems to be based on the dimensions of the image.  Anything over 66,000 pixels (such as 600x110) will cause the failure. This still seems to only happen on certain devices, all running the same version of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that I wind up responding to the last thread I answered about this issue almost 2 years ago.

It seems the most recent update to Chrome on Android (V 43.0.2357.78) causes new failures to jSignature.  If the page is in it's native size (no browser zooming), it works properly. If you zoom the screen, it fails.  This is new behavior (on existing code).  Other browsers seem to work properly.